# Unable to login in vercel using next auth

Tags: authentication, next.js, vercel, next-auth

Auth is working fine in development but in production it is not working. I get toast success pop up but still it does not login. I have added NEXTAUTH_URL in vercel environment but even that did not help.

I was trying to login but it does not login.

Comment: The same here. I didn't do a new deployment and the problem appeared today.